# What's the storage size of BIT(1)?

Tags: mysql, database, storage

I'd always thought that the storage size of a `BIT(1)` column is 1 bit.

But http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html

states that it is approximately (1+7)/8 bytes = 1 byte = **8 bits**.

If I have 32000 rows of `BIT(1)` data, does it mean that it takes 32000 * (1+7)/8 bytes = 32000 bytes of storage ?

Comment: What is your question? BTW, have you ever seen a file that was 1 bit long?

Comment: @Ingo I've not seen a file that was 1 bit long, but what's the storage requirement for 32000 rows of BIT(1) data? is it 32k bits or 32k bytes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BIT(M)  approximately (M+7)/8 bytes

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

-> data needs to be aligned so mysql need multiples of byte

Comment: If I have 1000 rows of BIT(1) data, does it mean that it takes 1000 * (1+7)/8 bytes = 1000 bytes of data?

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes. It also means that if you have 1000 rows of BIT(8) data, you'd still need 1000 bytes.

Comment: @ypercube so what's the point of BIT(1) at all ? isn't it supposed to be the datatype for storing booleans ?

Comment: @ypercube if we sub M=8 in the expression `1000* ((M+7)/8 bytes)` we will get 1875 bytes no?

Comment: I assumed that `15/8=1` (division with remainder).

Answer (score 2):

What this means is that the database engine can't store just one bit. It will combine all bit fields in a table and store them together until it reaches the minimum size it can store on disk (say 4 bytes on a 32 bit machine). The next bit field will be stored in a second 4-byte memory slot.

So on this typical 32 bit machine, one bit or 32 bits will need 4 bytes, and 33 bits would need 8 bytes.

Comment: Yes, but the minimum would be 1 byte, not 4, even on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: Not talking of the indexes, the system tables, the description of the table, columns, ...

Comment: @Charles are you saying that if I had 32k rows of `BIT(1)` the total storage is `32k bits`? Because if we sub `M=1` in the expression `32k*((M+7)/8 bytes)` we will get `32k bytes` not `32k bites` right?

Comment: @Pacerior,  No the rules I describe only apply within one row of data in a table. There is a minimum size for each row which is at least the minimum memory size of memory on the box.  So, on a 64 Bit machine,  if you had 32k rows of 1 x Bit(1), or 32 k rows where each row had 64 x Bit(1), in both case each row will take at least 8 bytes and you will have consume 32k x 8  = 256k bytes of disk space.

Comment: The point is that it doesn;t matter whetyher you have one bit field or 64 bit fields in each row. In both cases it will take 8 bytes because that is the minimum amount of memory which can be allocated and used on a 64 bit machine.  i.e, memory is always allocated in 64 bit (8 byte) chunks.