# What is the best way to effient MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I have a many column in database settings, for example:

1. show_user
2. show_product
3. show_category
4. show_history
   so on...
5. show_last_index

It's about 50++ column with type tinyint column.

Is it ok to have many column in MySQL? or are there a efficient way to make it more simple? So I have a little column with same settings.

Comment: MySQL's limit is 4096 columns per table (with a combined data limit of 64KiB). So your 50 `tinyint` columns are fine as that's 50 bytes, or 0.0076% of the maximum possible row size.

Comment: That said, why use `tinyint` instead of `bit` for boolean values?

Comment: @Schwern A single `bit(1)` takes 1 byte, yes. But most storage engines for MySQL will combine `bit(1)` fields together, so having one, two, three, four to eight `bit(1)` columns will still use 1 byte in total, and 9 `bit(1)` columns will use two bytes, and so on. That's mentioned in another answer to the same posting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7785673/159145

Comment: @Dai Ahh, I mixed up and tested multiple rows with a single bit column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than making a big table with every possible pair, it may be simpler to make a table with one row per pair. <strike>This will be more efficient on space if many are left at their defaults.</strike>.

Assuming these are associated with a user...

```
create table user_config (
  user_id bigint not null,
  name varchar(255) not null,
  value tinyint not null,
  primary key(name, user_id),
  constraint fk_user_config foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
);
```

The primary key ensures each user does not have duplicate pairs. I've deliberately put `name` first so the primary key index can be used for `where name = ?` and the foreign key index for `where user_id = ?`.

I've set the value `not null` on the assumption that `null` means "use the application default" in which case you might as well save some space and delete the row. YMMV.

## Pros

You can't have per-pair defaults in this schema. I argue this is a good thing because that's a business rule which should not be hard coded in the schema.

Adding a new pair does not require altering the table making development easier, especially if the table gets very large.

## Cons

All values must have the same type, but you've got that in your design already.

If you use `bit(1)` instead of `tinyint`, 50+ columns will likely use less disk space than a key/value table.

---

You could also store a single [json](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) column which would also be sparse, but my experience with JSON says that mixing SQL and NoSQL paradigms invites new problems. Avoid JSON if it can be done with a traditional SQL schema.